# sed - finding (and editing) a line with exactly three colons (not adjacent)

Tags: sed

I need to append some characters to the end of the the one line in a file which contains within it exactly three colon (`:`) characters.  The three `:` characters will not be adjacent.

Originally the line I needed to edit contained the characters `/16`, and I was able to successfully find and edit it using the `sed` command:

```
sed "/\/16/ s/$/ ${runid} ${dirname} ${doc}/" $logname  > $logname.new
```

However the application has changed and the characters `/16` no longer appear on the target line.  The only way I can find it now is to find the line containing exactly three `:` characters.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sed "s/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*$/s/$/ ${runid} ${dirname} ${doc}/" $logname  > $logname.new
```

where

- `[^:]*` any number of symbol not a colon
- `^` and `$` are begin and end of line.

This could probably be golfed.